# Android ACTION_SEND intent not populating Subject or Body

Tags: android, android-intent

I have code in my app which lets the user send an email to the developer.  It is supposed to prepopulate the To field, the Subject field, and the body field.  HOwever, when I run, it populates To but ignores the other EXTRAs like Subject, Body, and Chooser text.  I'm seeing this behavior on two test devices: one running Lollipop (Verizon Samsung Galaxy Note 4) and one running Jelly Bean 4.2.2 (Samsung Fascinate on CM10.1, although I don't know if this has bearing on the issue.

```
private void sendHelpEmail() {
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    // prompts email clients only
    email.setType("message/rfc822");

    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {getString(R.string.about_email)});
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.login_help_subject));
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.login_help_body, classButton.text(), Txt_Student.getText().toString()));

    try {
        // the user can choose the email client
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, getString(R.string.login_help_chooser)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(mThis, R.string.login_help_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

Why would Subject and Body get ignored when the To email is populated?

Comment: I wonder if some e-mail client applications that received that intent ignore the extras.

Comment: It's even ignoring the Chooser text before selecting an application.  Then the application I'm selecting is Gmail, so it seems that there should be some intent that at least works with Gmail.

Comment: When I've created an Intent for emailing, I used a single argument constructor for the Intent (just the action). You shouldn't need the mailto: piece. Also, you shouldn't have to call setType().

Comment: Same code works for me. I'd suggest you to verify that your string resources are okay (including not overridden in current language/flavor/etc.).

Comment: Weird. What are you using? I get the same result even when I replace resources with hard-coded strings.

Comment: Galaxy Note 4, Lollipop (5.0.1). Works for Gmail, Outlook and built-in email client. Please post your answer when you'll find the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code works for me (just tried it):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"foo@bar.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose email...");
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // handle edge case where no email client is installed
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT.ACTION_SENDTO);`
Only brings up email clients but for some reason doesn't populate the `SUBJECT` and `BODY` fields in some devices. ( I think these are edge cases).

`Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT.ACTION_SEND);`
Brings up all apps that can send multipart messages, for example: WhatsApp, Telegram, Gmail etc. but always populates the `SUBJECT` and `BODY` fields in all devices.

Comment: Thanks, using `ACTION_SEND` instead of `ACTION_SENDTO` workarounded the bug of missing subject, *but* the fact that brigns up other apps besides email apps is _very_ annoying! I can understand WhatsApp and Telegram, but why on Earth apps like ***Google Maps*** are there? - It's unbeliavable that after TWO AND A HALF YEARS from your answer Google still has not fixed this BIG BUG in Android APIs. ("Some device" is not an excuse for Google, since it is not an excuse my clients are willing to accept by me)

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways to overcome this. The very simple explanation is that in Api 29, and Api 30, some subtle changes to the Android system affect the way the incoming data is received and in short, the Uri.parse("mailto:") bit, and the Intent Extras, are sort of "colliding" (doing the same thing), and the receiving app isn't sure where to bring the data from.

Answer in Kotlin because it's 2023 and I'd never recommend an Engineer to write new Android code in Java in 2023 :-)

Method 1 - Give all information inside the Uri.parse

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
val subject = "Some email subject"
intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:firstaddress@email.com,secondaddress@email.com?subject=$subject")
startActivity(intent)
```

Result

Method 2 - Use your own Intent "Selector"

With so many different apps able to handle all sorts of intents, you can specify, in an intent, a separate Intent which is the "selector", which just means you can define the behave for what apps are offered. This means you can build out the email data purely in Intent Extras, but define the chooser sheet using the "mailto" method. Example code:

```
val selectorIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
selectorIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:") // this ensures only email apps offered
 
val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("address@mail.com", "anotheraddress@mail.com"))
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The subject")
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The email body")
emailIntent.selector = selectorIntent
 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this method it works for me.

```
private void sendMail() {

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "xx@xx.com", null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getResources().getString(R.string.mail_txt));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));

}
```

Comment: No, it's really bizarre - this code which seems to work for other people is not working on either of my test devices

Answer (score 0):

I've modified this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mksantoki/b495c1b08af4f1f114edfc9f48e66352) as given below, this util class anyone can modify as per their need, and it will help a lot for the email actions.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Patterns;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public final class IntentEmail {
    private final Context context;
    private final Set<String> to = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    private final Set<String> cc = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    private final Set<String> bcc = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    private String subject;
    private String body;
    private File attachment;
    private String intentChooser;

    private IntentEmail(@NonNull Context context) {
        this.context = checkNotNull(context);
    }


    public static IntentEmail from(@NonNull Context context) {
        return new IntentEmail(context);
    }

    private static <T> T checkNotNull(T object) {
        if (object == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument must not be null");
        }
        return object;
    }

    static String encodeRecipient(String recipient) {
        int index = recipient.lastIndexOf('@');
        String localPart = recipient.substring(0, index);
        String host = recipient.substring(index + 1);
        return Uri.encode(localPart) + "@" + Uri.encode(host);
    }

    static String fixLineBreaks(String text) {
        return text.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n").replace('\r', '\n').replaceAll("\n", "\r\n");
    }

    public IntentEmail setIntentChooser(@Nullable String intentChooser) {
        this.intentChooser = intentChooser;
        return this;
    }

    public IntentEmail attachment(@Nullable File attachment) {
        this.attachment = attachment;
        return this;
    }

    public IntentEmail to(@NonNull String to) {
        checkEmail(to);
        this.to.add(to);
        return this;
    }

    public IntentEmail to(@NonNull Collection<String> to) {
        checkNotNull(to);
        for (String email : to) {
            checkEmail(email);
        }
        this.to.addAll(to);
        return this;
    }

    public IntentEmail cc(@NonNull String cc) {
        checkEmail(cc);
        this.cc.add(cc);
        return this;
    }

    public IntentEmail cc(@NonNull Collection<String> cc) {
        checkNotNull(cc);
        for (String email : cc) {
            checkEmail(email);
        }
        this.cc.addAll(cc);
        return this;
    }

    public IntentEmail bcc(@NonNull String bcc) {
        checkEmail(bcc);
        this.bcc.add(bcc);
        return this;
    }

    public IntentEmail bcc(@NonNull Collection<String> bcc) {
        checkNotNull(bcc);
        for (String email : bcc) {
            checkEmail(email);
        }
        this.bcc.addAll(bcc);
        return this;
    }

    public IntentEmail subject(@NonNull String subject) {
        checkNotNull(subject);
        checkNoLineBreaks(subject);
        this.subject = subject;
        return this;
    }

    public IntentEmail body(@NonNull String body) {
        checkNotNull(body);
        this.body = fixLineBreaks(body);
        return this;
    }

    public void startActivity() {
        Intent intent = build();
        if (!(context instanceof Activity)) {
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
        if(intentChooser != null){
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
        }else {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public Intent build() {
        Uri mailtoUri = constructMailtoUri();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, mailtoUri);
        if(attachment != null){
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(attachment));
        }
        return intent;
    }

    private Uri constructMailtoUri() {
        StringBuilder mailto = new StringBuilder(1024);
        mailto.append("mailto:");
        addRecipients(mailto, to);

        boolean hasQueryParameters;
        hasQueryParameters = addRecipientQueryParameters(mailto, "cc", cc, false);
        hasQueryParameters = addRecipientQueryParameters(mailto, "bcc", bcc, hasQueryParameters);
        hasQueryParameters = addQueryParameter(mailto, "subject", subject, hasQueryParameters);
        addQueryParameter(mailto, "body", body, hasQueryParameters);

        return Uri.parse(mailto.toString());
    }

    private boolean addQueryParameter(StringBuilder mailto, String field, String value, boolean hasQueryParameters) {
        if (value == null) {
            return hasQueryParameters;
        }
        mailto.append(hasQueryParameters ? '&' : '?').append(field).append('=').append(Uri.encode(value));
        return true;
    }

    private boolean addRecipientQueryParameters(StringBuilder mailto, String field, Set<String> recipients, boolean hasQueryParameters) {
        if (recipients.isEmpty()) {
            return hasQueryParameters;
        }
        mailto.append(hasQueryParameters ? '&' : '?').append(field).append('=');
        addRecipients(mailto, recipients);
        return true;
    }

    private void addRecipients(StringBuilder mailto, Set<String> recipients) {
        if (recipients.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        for (String recipient : recipients) {
            mailto.append(encodeRecipient(recipient));
            mailto.append(',');
        }
        mailto.setLength(mailto.length() - 1);
    }

    private void checkEmail(String email) {
        checkNotNull(email);
        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is not a valid email address (according to " +
                    "Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS)");
        }
    }

    private void checkNoLineBreaks(String text) {
        boolean containsCarriageReturn = text.indexOf('\r') != -1;
        boolean containsLineFeed = text.indexOf('\n') != -1;
        if (containsCarriageReturn || containsLineFeed) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument must not contain line breaks");
        }
    }
}
```

**How To Use:**

```
try {
    IntentEmail.from(this)
        .to("mailId@mail.com")
        .subject(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .body("Body Text")
        .attachment(file)
        .setIntentChooser("Send Email")
        .startActivity();
} catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.e(e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Literally just had this problem and here's how I solved it:

Check if the email client (in my particular case, Gmail) isn't just re-using an unsent rough instead of composing a new email as when doing that the client seems to ignore both `Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT` and `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`.

Comment: What is an "unsent rough"?  This isn't much of a "solution".  Seems like it might be a bit of good advice for debugging, but with the ambiguous term "unsent rough" it's hard to know what the intention is here.